# RStudio Amazon EC2 Instance running out of disk space

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, rstudio

I have set up an AWS EC2 Instance which had running RStudio. I have been able to log into RStudio using 000.000.000.000:8787. I was getting some errors regarding writing to the disk and some memory errors at the last time of using RStudio so I decided to "stop" the EC2 Instance and then "start" it back up again. All of a sudden I am unable to log back into RStudio using the IP address assigned on port 8787.

It appears I ran out of memory on the EC2 instance, however all I have on the instance is a few R scripts and some small datasets. So, I believe it could be the case that R has used up the space somehow. I run `df -Th` in the terminal and the output is:

```
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs  7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     1.6G   29M  1.6G   2% /run
/dev/xvda1     ext4       49G   49G     0 100% /
tmpfs          tmpfs     7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs     7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0     squashfs   90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/8268
/dev/loop1     squashfs   18M   18M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/1480
/dev/loop2     squashfs   90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/8213
/dev/loop3     squashfs   55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1650
/dev/loop4     squashfs   55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1288
/dev/loop5     squashfs  768K  768K     0 100% /snap/gifski/1
tmpfs          tmpfs     1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1000
```

So it looks like `/dev/xvda1     ext4       49G   49G     0 100% /` is using all the space available.

I also run `sudo du -aBM -d 1 . | sort -nr | head -20` Which gives:

```
277M    .
102M    ./rstudio-1.2.5019-amd64.deb.1
102M    ./rstudio-1.2.5019-amd64.deb
37M     ./rstudio-server-1.2.1335-amd64.deb
34M     ./ROBUSTNESS_Add_FAKE_dates_model_R_code_function_to_make_09_01_2020.out
4M      ./R_code_function_to_make_average_shap_plots_07_01_2020.out
1M      ./permissions_on_aws.txt
1M      ./iris_test.pdf
1M      ./R_code_function_to_make_average_shap_plots_07_01_2020.err
1M      ./R_code_function_to_make_average_shap_plots.out
1M      ./ROBUSTNESS_Add_FAKE_dates_model_R_code_function_to_make_09_01_2020.err
1M      ./.ssh
1M      ./.profile
1M      ./.gnupg
1M      ./.cache
1M      ./.bashrc
1M      ./.bash_logout
1M      ./.bash_history
0M      ./R_code_function_to_make_average_shap_plots.err
0M      ./.sudo_as_admin_successful
```

I additionally run `find / -size +10M+`

```
/proc/kcore
find: ‘/proc/3338/task/3338/fd/6’: No such file or directory
find: ‘/proc/3338/task/3338/fdinfo/6’: No such file or directory
find: ‘/proc/3338/fd/5’: No such file or directory
find: ‘/proc/3338/fdinfo/5’: No such file or directory
/home/USER/myRfiles/myEnvironment.RData
```

Okay so my `myEnvironment.RData` is taking up a lot of space. I check how much by navigating to it using FileZilla and I see that its taking up 9.8 GB in size. Thats quite a lot but I have 50GB of space available so where is the other 40 GB gone?

I have also used `sudo apt-get autoremove` which only removed 4MB of space. I also removed the `.rstudio` files incase that was taking up too much space.

**EDIT:**

I run `du -cha --max-depth=1 / | grep -E "M|G"` which gives this output:

```
100M    /boot
15M     /sbin
5.5G    /usr
du: cannot access '/proc/3811/task/3811/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/3811/task/3811/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/3811/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/3811/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
919M    /snap
1.2G    /var
224M    /lib
5.8M    /lib32
7.2M    /etc
15M     /bin
11G     /home
19G     /
19G     total
```

I have access to 50 GB of space on the Amazon AWS EC2 Instance and here it's telling me I am only using 19GB...

**Additional step (mostly for my thought process)**

I then run `du -cha --max-depth=1 /home | grep -E "M|G"` since it takes up the most memory. With the following output:

```
277M    /home/ubuntu
11G     /home/MYUSER
11G     /home
11G     total
```

I go a little deeper: `du -cha --max-depth=1 /home/MYUSER | grep -E "M|G"`

Which gives:

```
7.3M    /home/MYUSER/MlBayesOpt
728M    /home/MYUSER/chapter_3
188M    /home/MYUSER/chapter_1
25M     /home/MYUSER/gganim
58M     /home/MYUSER/.cargo
2.5M    /home/MYUSER/financial_markets_R
165M    /home/MYUSER/.rstudio
9.6G    /home/MYUSER/pollution
11G     /home/MYUSER
11G     total
```

So I see 11GB being used with 9.6 GB in the folder `pollution`. I have 50GB available so I don't mind spending 10GB on this folder.

Comment: You are possibly confusing "memory" with "disk space". "Memory" normally refers to RAM, whereas `du` command report on disk space.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `000.000.000.000:8787`? Are you logging into the instance, then using some software to refer to `000.000.000.000:8787`? If so, this means it is accessing port `8787` on the same computer. Also, please note that when an EC2 instance is stopped and started, it might receive a different Public IP address. So, check that you are logging into the correct "new" public IP address.

Comment: What I mean by `000.000.000.000:8787` is that each time I start the EC2 Instance I obtain a new IP address but the port always stays the same. I just paste the new IP address into the browser along with the port `8787` and I would usually get to the RStudio login screen. However now I just get `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` so from my understanding the problem occurs due to there being no space left on the Instance for RStudio to create the `.rstudio` folder. "I think" I need help trying to identify where the space is being used up so I can delete the files which are taking up all the space.

Comment: To add a quick update. I increased the volume from 50GB to 60GB and removed some files manually using FileZilla (such as the folder `.rstudio`). I restarted the instance and I am now able to login again. However I think this is just papering over the cracks and I am sure to run into the problem again.